# Error al generar excel con PHPExcel

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpexcel

Tengo un metodo generico que se encarga de generar los excel que necesito, lo que le envio al metodo es el resource de una consulta, el metodo se encarga de recorrer el resultado para generar el excel con las culumnas y las filas correspondientes.

Como mencione genero varios archivos de excel de diferentes consultas, y hoy me encuentro generandon uno más, el problema viene que al generar el excel al incio del excel me anexa un espacio en blanco o mejor dicho una linea en blanco \n , y esto ocaciona que no se visualize el archivo con la paqueteria de office

Asi inicia el excel antes de esta linea hay una linea en blanco,

```
PK    FušJG’D²X  ð     [Content_Types].xml­”MNÃ0…÷œ"ò%nY „švAa  •(0ö¤±êØ–gúw{&i‰@ÕnbEö{ßøyìÑdÛ¸l
```

En codigo hexadecimal ya indentifique el caracter

```
0d0a
```

Ya investigue sobre el caracter y lo que encontre fue lo que mencione una linea en banco \n o una linea nueva que en php es PHP_EOL

```
var_dump(urlencode(PHP_EOL)); ?>
```

Resultado : `'%0D%0A'`

Y ese es mi codigo:

```
 <?php
   $parametro1 =  isset($_GET['a'])?$_REQUEST['a']:date('Y-m');
$parametro2 = isset($_REQUEST['b'])?$_REQUEST['b']:0;
$parametro3 = isset($_REQUEST['c'])?$_REQUEST['c']:0;
$parametro4 = isset($_REQUEST['d'])?$_REQUEST['d']:0;
$parametro5 = isset($_REQUEST['e'])?$_REQUEST['e']:0;
$parametro6 = $_REQUEST['f'];

$parametro7=$_GET['param'];

session_start();

require 'Datos.class.php';
require_once '../../../php/lib/PHPExcel/generarExcel.php';

$datos=Datos::getInstance();

$resultado = $datos->QueryExcel($parametro1,$parametro2,$parametro3,$parametro4,$parametro5,$parametro6);

GeneraExcel($resultado, 'TITULOEXCEL', $_SESSION['nombre'],'NombredelArchivo');
```

GeneraExcel es un metodo que se encarga de recorrer el resource, ya esta implementado y funciona correctamente para todos los excel que genero excepto para este nuevo.

Y la linea que se agrega en mi archvo de manera automatica yo en ningun momento lo agrego en mi codigo, no se de donde sale.

Quizas sea algo muy sencillo que estoy dejando pasar por ahi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Anexo el metodo de GeneraExcel

```
<?php
/**
 * [$ruta description]Gnerar Excel
 * @var null
 */
function GeneraExcel($result, $tituloReporte, $usuario, $nombreArchivo)
{
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
        if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
            die('Este archivo solo se puede ver desde un navegador web');
        /** Se agrega la libreria PHPExcel */
        require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
        // Se crea el objeto PHPExcel
        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
        // Se asignan las propiedades del libro
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator($usuario)//Autor
        ->setLastModifiedBy($usuario)//Ultimo usuario que lo modificó
        ->setTitle("Reporte excel")
            ->setSubject("Reporte excel")
            ->setDescription("Reporte excel")
            ->setKeywords("Reporte excel")
            ->setCategory("Reporte excel");

        // Obtenemos los nombres de las columnas y la cantidad de columnas.
        $titulosColumnas = array();
        $columnas = mysql_num_fields($result);
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $columnas; $i++ ) 
        {
            array_push($titulosColumnas,mysql_field_name( $result, $i ));
        }

        $letraFinal = GetLetras($columnas-1);

        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->mergeCells('A1:'.$letraFinal.'1');

        // Se agregan los titulos del reporte
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', $tituloReporte);

        for ( $i = 0; $i < $columnas; $i++ )
        {
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue(GetLetras($i).'3', $titulosColumnas[$i]);
        }

        $r=4;
        while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            for ( $i = 0; $i < $columnas; $i++ )
            {
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue(GetLetras($i).$r,$fila[$titulosColumnas[$i]]);
            }
            $r++;
        }

        $estiloTituloReporte = array(
            'font' => array(
                'name' => 'Verdana',
                'bold' => true,
                'italic' => false,
                'strike' => false,
                'size' => 16,
                'color' => array(
                    'rgb' => 'FFFFFF'
                )
            ),
            'fill' => array(
                'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                'color' => array('argb' => 'FF220835')
            ),
            'borders' => array(
                'allborders' => array(
                    'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_NONE
                )
            ),
            'alignment' => array(
                'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
                'vertical' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
                'rotation' => 0,
                'wrap' => TRUE
            )
        );

        $estiloTituloColumnas = array(
            'font' => array(
                'name' => 'Arial',
                'bold' => true,
                'color' => array(
                    'rgb' => 'FFFFFF'
                )
            ),
            'fill' => array(
                'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_GRADIENT_LINEAR,
                'rotation' => 90,
                'startcolor' => array(
                    'rgb' => '00004d'
                ),
                'endcolor' => array(
                    'argb' => '00004d'
                )
            ),
            'borders' => array(
                'top' => array(
                    'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_MEDIUM,
                    'color' => array(
                        'rgb' => '000000'
                    )
                )
            ),
            'alignment' => array(
                'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
                'vertical' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
                'wrap' => TRUE
            ));

        $estiloInformacion = new PHPExcel_Style();
        $estiloInformacion->applyFromArray(
            array(
                'font' => array(
                    'name' => 'Arial',
                    'color' => array(
                        'rgb' => '000000'
                    )
                ),
                'fill' => array(
                    'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                    'color' => array('rgb' => 'ffffff')
                ),
                'borders' => array(
                    'left' => array(
                        'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,
                        'color' => array(
                            'rgb' => '000000'
                        )
                    )
                )
            ));

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:'.$letraFinal.'1')->applyFromArray($estiloTituloReporte);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3:'.$letraFinal.'3')->applyFromArray($estiloTituloColumnas);
        //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setSharedStyle($estiloInformacion, "A4:".$letraFinal . ($columnas - 1));

        for ($i = 'A'; $i <= $letraFinal; $i++) {
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->getColumnDimension($i)->setAutoSize(TRUE);
        }

        // Se asigna el nombre a la hoja
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('REGISTROS');

        // Se activa la hoja para que sea la que se muestre cuando el archivo se abre
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        // Inmovilizar paneles
        //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->freezePane('A4');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->freezePaneByColumnAndRow(0, 4);

        // Se manda el archivo al navegador web, con el nombre que se indica (Excel2007)
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$nombreArchivo.'.xlsx"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
        exit;
    } else {
        print_r('No hay resultados para mostrar');
    }
}


function GetLetras($i)
{
    $letras = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
    return $letras[$i];
}
?>
```

Comment: creo que deberías enseñar tu metodo GenerarExcel, que es lo que hace, porque creo que el problema principal esta ahí y no en la query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se sé si será tu código exacto, pero tienes dos errores que podrían provocar ese problema:

- Tu programa PHP empieza con un espacio en blanco. Eso produce el envío de datos antes del excel (pone `_<?php`).
- El carácter que indicas suele producirse por el mismo problema anterior generado por un retorno del carro antes o después de alguna apertura o cierre de PHP (`<?php` o `?>`).

Ya que no disponemos del código completo para averiguar dónde estás dejando ese carácter adicional (como el archivo `Datos.class.php`), te recomiendo que revises concienzudamente cada apertura y cierre de PHP para comprobar que no haya ningún carácter ni salto de línea adicional (puedes usar un editor hexadecimal si te sientes cómodo manejándolos).

Un truco temporal usando [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/ob_start) y [ob_end_clean()](http://php.net/ob_end_clean) podría ser el siguiente:

```
<?php
/* Introducimos en el buffer todo lo generado de manera involuntaria */
ob_start();
$parametro1 = isset($_GET['a'])?$_REQUEST['a']:date('Y-m');
$parametro2 = isset($_REQUEST['b'])?$_REQUEST['b']:0;
$parametro3 = isset($_REQUEST['c'])?$_REQUEST['c']:0;
$parametro4 = isset($_REQUEST['d'])?$_REQUEST['d']:0;
$parametro5 = isset($_REQUEST['e'])?$_REQUEST['e']:0;
$parametro6 = $_REQUEST['f'];

$parametro7=$_GET['param'];

session_start();

require 'Datos.class.php';
require_once '../../../php/lib/PHPExcel/generarExcel.php';

$datos=Datos::getInstance();

$resultado = $datos->QueryExcel($parametro1, $parametro2, $parametro3, $parametro4, $parametro5, $parametro6);

/* Guardamos la información que se ha generado para su depuración */
file_put_contents('archivo.log.txt', ob_get_contents());
/* Limpiamos cualquier salida que antes iba al navegador de manera accidental
  antes de enviar el excel */
ob_end_clean();
GeneraExcel($resultado, 'TITULOEXCEL', $_SESSION['nombre'], 'NombredelArchivo');
```

---

**Recomendaciones:**

Usar `ob_start()` y `ob_end_clean()` son parches para ocultar un problema de fondo que hay que encontrar y solucionar.

Tal y como recomienda [PSR-2 (apartado #2.2)](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#files) los archivos que contienen únicamente PHP (o, en general, aquellos que no generan HTML) deben omitir el cierre de PHP `?>` para evitar que se "cuelen" (algunos editores agregan automáticamente una línea vacía al final de los archivos de texto) espacios en blanco o retornos del carro indeseados.

> **2.2. Files**
>
> All PHP files MUST use the Unix LF (linefeed) line ending.
>
> All PHP files MUST end with a single blank line.
>
> The closing `?>` tag MUST be omitted from files containing only PHP.

La traducción vendría a ser:

> **2.2. Archivos**
>
> Todos los archivos PHP **DEBEN** usar el final de línea de Unix LF (linefeed / avance de línea).
>
> Todos los archivos PHP **DEBEN** terminar en una única línea en blanco.
>
> La etiqueta de cierre `?>` **DEBE** ser omitida en archivos que contengan únicamente PHP.

Por lo tanto, deberías quitar el cierre de PHP que tienes en el archivo que contiene la función `GeneraExcel` y en `Datos.class.php` y probar de nuevo para ver si ese era el problema.

Comment: Que cres bro, funciono con: ob_start(); y ob_end_clean(); Gracias!!!!

Comment: De nada. He agregado una edición para arreglar el problema. Lo de `ob_start` y `ob_end_clean` son parches para ocultarlo, no solucionarlo. Prueba lo que te propongo y me cuentas.

Comment: ¿Has probado a hacer lo que te recomendé?

Comment: Aun no, pero lo probaré y en cuanto lo haga te menciono si funciono.

Comment: Ya verifique y no, no son las etiquetas de cierre y de apertura,  ob_start();
$datos=Datos::getInstance();
ob_end_clean(); en problema esta en la instancia de la clase public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!(self::$_instance instanceof self)) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

Comment: Lo siento, se cortó el mensaje :( Siempre se puede volcar a un archivo la información que salió para su posterior depuración. ¿Te pongo un ejemplo?

Comment: estaría bien, para tener una idea mas clara

Comment: Hecho. He agregado código para guardar en un archivo la información que iba a salir por el navegador antes que el excel: `file_put_contents('archivo.log.txt', ob_get_contents());`. Echa un vistazo al archivo que se crea y dime qué contiene.

Comment: este es el resultado que retorna:  string(2) " "

Comment: Habría que ver el contenido binario, podrían ser dos espacios, uno y un avance de línea o un avance de línea y retorno del carro.. también podría ser el BOM de un archivo UTF8 con él..

Comment: este es el resultado en binario la linea que se añade y que corrompe el archivo es este : 0d0a el resultado es lo mismo que las imagenes que puse haya arriba

Comment: Retorno del carro y nueva línea.. todo apunta a que algún script PHP que tienes cierra PHP al final (`?>`) y hay una línea adicional. Por eso PSR-2 recomienda *no cerrar PHP* al final del script. O quizá me equivoque y sea algún cierre/apertura dentro de un script en dos líneas diferentes.

Comment: ok, seguiré verificando para encontrar el error, gracias!

Comment: ¡Suerte! Si usas Linux puedo indicarte un comando para hacer una búsqueda rápida.

Answer (score 0):

Las veces que he utilizado PHPExcel y me ha generado un pantallazo como el que adjuntas, el error NO ERA DE PHPExcel, sino de algun punto anterior, es decir, seguramente te este retornando el php algun error y te lo "imprime" en el excel, el cual no sabe interpretar y saca cosas raras..
Prueba ha hacer un print_r de los valores que desas imprimir