# Caracteres extraños utilizando PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Estoy utilizando PHPExcel para descargar en formato excel una información,
pero al realizar la prueba genera estos caracteres y no me descarga dicho archivo:

[image: CARACTERES EXTRAÑOS]

La manera como lo estoy descargando es la siguiente.:

Después de terminar el ciclo que va insertar datos al archivo, adiciono estas líneas de código:

```
<?php
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('filename');

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);   

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: "inline ; filename="prueba.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

    header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
    header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
    header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
    header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: habría que ver código, seguramente falten las cabeceras de descarga fijate en esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/199278/81450 eso sumado a `$objWriter->save('php://output');` debería iniciar la descarga o mostrar el cuadro de diálogo "guardar como"

Comment: @aloMalbarez Ya modifique la pregunta adicionando las lineas de código con el cual se descarga el archivo

Comment: un archivo xlsx es un zip que contiene xml, el archivo en binario empieza con la firma `"PK\x01\x02"` (archivo de tipo zip), luego cabeceras, nombre del primer archivo, etc... en la captura se ve que hay un `null } `extra. estas usando un framework? hay algo después del save?

Comment: @aloMalbarez te está dando la mejor pista para saber lo que te está pasando. El formato ZIP comienza por "PK", por lo que todo lo que tengas antes lo has generado en tu PHP (quizá algún bloque de depuración, un `echo`, `var_dump`, etc). Elimina todas las líneas que den salida de texto antes de generar tu Excel o bien usa `ob_start()` como proponen en estas respuestas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/72040/excel-no-puede-abrir-el-archivo-prueba-xls-porque-el-formato-o-la-extensión-de#72089 y https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65722/error-al-generar-excel-con-phpexcel#65867

Comment: Son respuestas de @OscarGarcia que me ayudaron mucho.

Comment: Hola @NorbeyMartinez , cuando leas estas palabras déjanos un mensaje para intentar ayudarte con el problema si aún no lo has solucionado.

Answer (score 0):

debe terminar con un exit();

```
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit();
```